# image merging using php in GD

Tags: php, gd

i want to merge two images in php using GD how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

see [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/imagecopymerge) and/or [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)